# Access Denied for user 'linuxuser'@'localhost' (using password: no)

Tags: permissions, apache2, php, mysql

My client asked me to move his Wordpress site from a shared server to AWS.

The AWS EC2 instance is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with PHP 5.5.9 with MySQL 5.5.38.
Old server has PHP 5.4.30 and MySQL 5.5.42.
There is no PHPMyAdmin and CPanel installed on AWS instance. So I have to do everything using commands.

In AWS instance, I have sudo access as 'ubuntu' user. I created a new Linux user 'wpsite' and created home directory for it. I managed to transfer all files & directories from old server to `/home/wpsite/public_html`.

Then I created a new database 'WP_DB', and a new MySQL user 'wp_db_user' and granted all access to WP_DB.

```
CREATE USER wp_db_user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'thepwd';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON WP_DB.* TO wp_db_user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'thepwd';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now, I changed wp-config.php file

```
define('DB_NAME', 'WP_DB');
define('DB_USER', 'wp_db_user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'thepwd');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Then I restored old WP database from sql dump, using wp_db_user account (tried with root user as well). Next, I created a vhost configuration in Apache2 with proper server name & alias, and directory path, and changed A-Record of the domain to AWS instance. Upto this point, everything went smooth. There were no error.

When I visit the website, the wordpress site is displayed, but problem is that certain contents are missing including title of site. I had a look at error log file and this error is listed in multiple lines:

```
PHP Warning: mysql_query(): Access Denied for user 'ubuntu'@'localhost' (using password: no) in /home/wpsite/public_html/wp-content/themes/enterprise-pro/front-page.php on line 5
```

and the said line contains following code

```
$sel_home = mysql_query("select * from admin_home_page");
```

Then I copied WP files in my local Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64bit), Apache/2.4.7, PHP 5.5.9, and MySQL 5.5.41. I see following error in log file.

```
PHP Warning: mysql_query(): Access Denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: no) in /home/wpsite/public_html/wp-content/themes/enterprise-pro/front-page.php on line 5
```

Point to note that the user mentioned in error message **is not a MySQL user**. It is a Linux user. I cannot pinpoint whether it is problem with Wordpress, PHP version, MySQL, or Linux Permissions. I am not pro in Linux either. I have done everything reading from blogs and other Stackoverflow questions.

The website is working fine in old server. I can also log in to WP admin section on new server, which uses same database without any error. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong, and what could be done to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: For further testing, I copied WP files in my Win 7 (64bit), Apache/2.2.22 (Win32), PHP/5.3.8, and MySQL 5.1.37. Everything worked. No error in log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version is your wordpress installation?

If it is >= 3.9 read this:

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/07/mysql-in-wordpress-3-9/

```
In WordPress 3.9, we added an extra layer to WPDB, causing it to switch to using 
the mysqli PHP library, when using PHP 5.5 or higher.

For plugin developers, this means that you absolutely shouldn’t be using PHP’s mysql_*() 
functions any more – you can use the equivalent WPDB functions instead.
```

So basically if you are using WP >= 3.9 and you are using PHP >= 5.5 you can not access db with mysql_* function (it is bad practice though, they are deprecated).

You should consider lowering PHP version if you do not want to change the code, or change the code to use $wpdb object instead.

The best solution will be to update your plugin you are using with the one for your WP version if it exists. You should seek the developer of the plugin.

Comment: It is version 4.1.1. But it is working on same version in Windows. I am not sure about the version in shared server, where the site is currently hosted.
I tend to use PDO. Actually the code is written by someone else. I can't downgrade to older version either as my other site is gonna be affected.

Comment: Can you confirm that you windows PHP version is >= 5.5? Caun you also check the shared hosting PHP version? Because the blog post I linked to you clearly states mysql_* functions are deprecated. You can replace all occurencies of mysql_* with $wpdb object to see if it will resolve your issues.

Comment: Yes my PHP version is > 5.5. But it makes sense because after I installed PHP 5.5 in my local Ubuntu box, there was an error regarding mysql_* functions. So I had to enable the extension. My Windows system has PHP 5.3.8. That's why it is working.

Comment: Is it possible to downgrade PHP version for one website in Ubuntu?

Comment: Basically if you are installing PHP from official repositories you will get the latest version there. You will have to purge current PHP, download old release package from php.net website and build from source. But this is out of the scope of the current question asked. You can also check for newer release of the plugin you are using for the right version of your WP installation.

Comment: sorry for late reply. Thank you for giving me direction.